# Crystal Reports - Hide Page Header on First Page

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2010

I have a report that needs to show a report header on page 1, and a different header on subsequent pages.

This seems simple enough; if I add `pagenumber=1 and goupnumber=1` to the suppress formula for the second header, it will only be shown after the first page. However, the report is also supposed to reset the page count several times in a single group, thus leaving several pages that match those criteria.

Is there another field in Crystal reports that could have a unique value for the first page? Or is there another way I might go about solving this?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "the report is supposed to reset the page count..." You shouldn't be able to reset the page count, so just putting `pagenumber=1` in the PH's suppression formula should work.

Comment: Like previous commenter says, you can't reset the page number inside a group. You can create a Running Total Field, but you still must have something tangible to count in your total. Do you have another item to group by inside of your main group? You can apply a running total to the second group and reset that on each change of group.

Answer (score 5):

You have to specify in the *Selection Expert - Suppress Formula* the following formula:

```
PageNumber = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

In the Supress Formula try this Formula
Drilldowngrouplevel = 1 ;

or

PageNumber=TotalPageCount

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify in the Selection Expert - second header - Suppress Formula the following formula:

PageNumber <> 1